# Netty channel.write not writing message

Tags: java, sockets, jboss, network-programming, netty

I'm trying to make my first steps with Netty, for this purpose I wrote simple server on Netty and simple client on oio plain TCP.

Client sends random text packet, and must receive "Ack" message.
See the handler method:

```
  @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

    ctx.write("Ack"); 
    ctx.flush();

    ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while (in.isReadable()) {
            sb.append((char) in.readByte());

        }
    } finally {
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
    }
    LOG.debug("Incoming message. ACK was send");

    String myaddr = ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString();
    String message = "Message from " + myaddr + " :" + sb.toString();
    LOG.debug(message);
    sendToOther(myaddr, message);

}
```

The problem is - when I try to send back "Ack" string - client receives nothing.
But when i try to send back message that incoming - it works fine, and i see echo in my client.

```
 @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

    ctx.write(msg); 
    ctx.flush();
```

`write()` method needs `Object` and I tried to send `(Object) String` - but nothing happened.
I also tried to send `ByteBuf` (I saw that in one article) and it's still not working too.

When I send back the incoming message as echo - it works. When I send thomething else - it doesn't. Please help me, i just can't figure where my mistake is.

---

I solved this problem. Point was, that you need to send `ByteBuff` only. So we need create it, and write something to it and only then we can write it into chanel pipe. in my case it was like :

```
String ack = "ACK";
    ByteBuf out = ctx.alloc().buffer(ack.length()*2);
    out.writeBytes(ack.getBytes());
    ctx.write(out); 
    ctx.flush();
    LOG.debug("Incoming message. ACK was send");
```

May be this is not exelent sollution, but it works as example.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You will see why it fails if you replace your

```
ctx.write("Ack"); 
ctx.flush();
```

in your serverHandler with the following:

```
ChannelFuture cf = ctx.write("Ack");
ctx.flush();
if (!cf.isSuccess()) {
    System.out.println("Send failed: " + cf.cause());
}
```

It should give you a message saying that `String` is not supported.

`ByteBuf` should work though:

```
ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Ack", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
ctx.flush();
```

on the client side edit the channelRead method:

```
ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
System.out.println("Client received: " + in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer! Your solution is better than i found myself.