# In netty, how we can send string messages with different arbitrary length?

Tags: java, netty

I want to send string message by netty. To do that I need to use StringDecoder and encoder as follows:

```
 ch.pipeline().addLast("frameDecoder", new LineBasedFrameDecoder(**maxLength**)); 
                 ch.pipeline().addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

                 // Encoder
                 ch.pipeline().addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
```

It is nice, but the only part that make me disappointed in the maxLengh?! I don't know the maximum size of my string messages? Why it needs that, it can find string by a delimiter or \r\n why it need the maxLength?

Is there any way to send string messages without specifying a length for them? And by the way, if I set the limit to a large number, and only use the small portion, do I loose anything? Am I wasting space?

I am writing a distributed key-value store, servers in my system replicate new write to each other, I don't know how large is a the value of a key.

Thanks

Comment: When I was using traditional server/client architecture, I used to easily use println() and readLine() to send an unlimited line. I wish I can do it using netty too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything has a beginning must have an end.  What if no LF is sent to the server?  That's why there is a max length.  I believe you should set a limit of line length when designing this kind of system.

If you set a very large number, and only short lines are received, no space is wasted.

Comment: So you thing if I set max length in the code to 1M (bytes), it is safe? I don't waist space because of that?

Comment: If only short lines are received, yes.   netty will check the length of the line and then create a byte buffer object of size == length.

Comment: Do you have any comment about my suggestion regarding searching for "\n" one-by-one? I think that is the only solution when we are seeking for a delimiter, so probably even netty itself is using that approach in LineBasedFrameDecoder.

Comment: I would suggest reading the code of netty.  Actually yes(based on 4.0.36-Final), in a better way :)

Answer (score 0):

I found another post that can be used for sending string: 
[Netty channel.write not writing message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760764/netty-channel-write-not-writing-message)

So using the method suggested there, I came up with this solution, but I don't if it is efficient.

Send:

```
 String str = "Hello";
 ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(str, CharsetUtil.UTF_8)); // (3)
```

Receive:

I first deifne an StringBuffer in the class as a member:

```
StringBuffer sBuf = new StringBuffer("");
```

Then in the channelRead I will have:

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    System.out.println("Inside channelRead");
    ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
    while (in.isReadable()) {
        byte b = in.readByte();
        char c = (char)b;
        System.out.print(c);
        if (c == '\n') {
            System.out.println("Client received: " + sBuf.toString());
            sBuf = new StringBuffer("");
        } else {

            sBuf.append(c);
        }
    }

    ctx.close();
    in.release();
}
```

I know, it does not looks efficient, but I check the java code for readLine() method of the BufferReader that I used to use in in the traditional way here: 
http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/io/BufferedReader-source.html

I think it is doing the same thing (which I don't like) it uses the StringBuffer and append method, it looks complex though, maybe that makes it more efficient than my simple idea :p

So what do you thing guys? I tested it, it works fine, the only concern is the efficiency.