# Socket connection Data Input Stream don't seem working

Tags: java, android, networking, netty

I am sending some bytes to the netty server from Android phones using Socket connections. When Netty server gets some bytes, it will send PONG message from server side which I am reading using `DataInputStream` `.readUTF`
Here is my SERVER HANDLER code

```
package com.nearbuy.fbb.netty.server.handler;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.nearbuy.fbb.netty.server.models.MetaDetails;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    private static final String CONNECTION_CLOSE_COMMAND = "image_streaming_close";
    private String imageFile = "";
    private static HashMap<String, byte[]> fileBytesMap = new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap<String, Integer[]> fileWHDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap<String, String> fileNameMap = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean isMetaReceived = false;
    private int PROCESS_ID_LENGTH = "PROCESS_ID".length();
    private MetaDetails metaDetails = new MetaDetails();
    private static final String META_DATA_ACKNOWLEDGE = "META_DATA_RECEIVING";
    private static final String CLOSE_CONNECTION = "CLOSE_CONNECTION";

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf inBuffer = (ByteBuf) msg;
        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[inBuffer.readableBytes()];
        inBuffer.readBytes(packetBytes);
        // some logics with bits
        writePongBackToClient(ctx);
    }
    private void writePongBackToClient(ChannelHandlerContext ctx){
ChannelFuture cf = ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("PONG", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        ctx.flush();
        if (!cf.isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println("Send failed: " + cf.cause());
        }
        System.out.println(cf.isDone());
    }
}
```

On the Android side I make a connection with Bootstrapserver which have the above handler. It gets the bytes from Android but when I writes bytes back to client, Datainputstream don't get it.
Here is client side

```
private void createSocketConnection(){
    try{
        socket = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, 9999);
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private boolean writeToSocketStream(byte [] byteArray) throws InterruptedException {
    try {

        Log.i("Writing bytes", "New byte came of Byte length is "+ byteArray.length);
        outputStream.write(byteArray);
        outputStream.flush();
        String pong = inputStream.readUTF();
        Log.i("Response ", pong);
        Log.i("Written bytes ", "Last bytes are not buffered, just written");
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it never gets any string from Datainputstream, it just hangs to that line :(
I am unable to determine where the actual problem is. Whether the server don't write message or client is having a problem.
If you need the server starter code then I can put it here :)
I checked from Server side using ChannelFuture that server write back but Android is not getting it

```
ChannelFuture cf = ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("PONG", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        ctx.flush();
        if (!cf.isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println("Send failed: " + cf.cause());
        }
        System.out.println(cf.isDone());
```

It prints true

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25762049/8181750) answer netty channel's `write` does not directly support Strings.

Comment: @L.Spillner I tried writing with Unpooled and Charsets UTF-8 but that didn't worked well :(